# AbilitySystemComp GetSet retrun null

Tags: unreal-engine5, unreal-gameplay-ability-system

I have been implementing GAS in a project of mine and something is bugging me to no end.

In this youtube [video](https://youtu.be/YvXvWa6vbAA?t=2087) made by unreal, they use the function

```
AttributeSet = AbilitySystemComponent->GetSet<UGASAbilityDemoAttributeSet>();
```

Where according to the video and the doc, `GetSet` is supposed to return the set if it exists or creates it and then give the newly created set. However, when I use it, it always returns `null` and I can't find a difference in my implementation.

What is it that I am doing wrong?

**Other Sources**

In the [docs](https://docs.unrealengine.com/5.0/en-US/gameplay-attributes-and-attribute-sets-for-the-gameplay-ability-system-in-unreal-engine/), they also mention to do the same.
I also downloaded and look at the implementation for the new Lyra demo project where it's a lot more complex, but in the end, they, themself, do the same.

**Note**

I know I can just

```
   MySet = CreateDefaultSubObject<UGASAbilityDemoAttributeSet>("My Set")
```

To create my set, but the fact that I'm unable to use it like they do bug me.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I found out that you have to first set the "Default Starting Data" on you Ability System Component in the editor. After that the `GetSet` method returns an object.
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ev91.png)